# Protocol members can only be marked unavailable in an @objc protocol

Tags: swift, syntax

I don't want to use @objc. Is there a pure swift solution to this problem?

```
public protocol Dequeable {      
    @available(iOS, deprecated: 10.0, obsoleted: 11.0, message: "Because ! Use 'hasXib' instead.") // errors here
    func register(cellType: DequeableComponentIdentifiable.Type, hasNib: Bool)
    func register(cellType: DequeableComponentIdentifiable.Type, hasXib: Bool)
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to use `@objc`?

Comment: No. It's just fugly.